# How to implement MouseListener to a non-GUI object within a certain area?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener, java-2d

I'm making a "whack a mole" game in Java. In my game panel class I have an array of holes (which can be set to mole). A hole is a separate object (there is a Hole class). Each Hole object is meant to be a circle with 100 px diameter. The graphical representation is a circle (`fillOval`) and `size=100` was used.

Can I implement `MouseListener` interface to the Hole object? Is it possible since Hole does not extend a `JComponent`, such as `JPanel`? Also is it possible to specify the mouse listener's scope to a specific area? For instance, I want only the clicks within the circular area to be counted, not the clicks within the square circumscribing the circular hole area.

(There isn't much more to my code right now than what I explained as my program structure.)

Comment: *"Can I implement MouseListener interface to the Hole object? Is it possible since Hole does not extend a JComponent, such as JPanel?"* - Since the "hole" is likely painted by a component, via it's `paintComponent` method, then you should add the `MouseListener` to that component and test if the `MouseEvent` occurred over one of the holes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `MouseListener` to the parent component. Have each `Hole` object provide a method that accepts a `Point` objects & returns `true` / `false` for whether that point lies within the area that would be painted by the `Hole`. When the user clicks the panel, it should contain code that will iterate the `Hole` objects checking each in turn.

> The graphical representation is a circle (`fillOval`) and `size=100` was used.

I'd upgrade that to using an [`Ellipse2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html). Since the ellipse implements `Shape`, it inherits the [`contains(Point2D)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains-java.awt.geom.Point2D-) method.